# tomcat webserver/servlet container/dispatcher servlet interaction in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

what is the flow diagram of interactions between tomcat web server/servlet container and dispatcher servlet . tomcat servlet container is separate from spring IOC container or applicationcontext ?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is a web server. It "knows" how to deal with web applications according to the web applications specification.
This specification defines means of servlets declaration, their order, etc. It also defines additional notions like filters, listeners, etc. This specification has nothing to do with spring. Basically, you can use tomcat to host the application with servlets, filters, listeners without spring dependencies, so you won't even have an application context.

With this in mind, Spring MVC (to which the Dispatcher Servlet actually belongs) is just a third-party among many others from the Tomcat standpoint.

`DispatcherServlet` is an ordinary servlet that the spring team has developed. It is an entry point to all spring infrastructure in web applications managed by a web server, it's a "glue" that acts as a "driver" - it loads the application context (all the beans), handles all the requests coming to the controllers, etc.